# How to access attributes of the group's object? AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'risk_level'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have two classes `GeoFence` and `Worker`. The class `GeoFence` has an attribute `risk_level` that is assigned randomly to all objects of this class.

I want to access this attribute `risk_level` from the class `Worker`. In particular, when I check the collision between the objects of these two classes (see the function `update` in `Worker`), I want to print the `risk_level` of particular geofence that the worker collides with.

Below I provide my code, but it fails with the error message:

> AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'risk_level'

So, I understand that it's necessary to access objects of the group, because the group itself does not have the attribute `risk_level`. But how can I do it?

```
import pygame

class GeoFence(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect, risk_level, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        self._layer = 1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((rect.width, rect.height))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = rect
        self.risk_level = risk_level


class Worker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

  # we introduce to possible states: RUNNING and IDLE
  RUNNING = 0
  IDLE = 1
  NUMBER_OF_ACCIDENTS = 0

  def __init__(self, image_running, image_idle, location, *groups):

    # each state has it's own image
    self.images = {
        Worker.RUNNING: pygame.transform.scale(get_image(image_running), (45, 45)),
        Worker.IDLE: pygame.transform.scale(get_image(image_idle), (20, 45))
    }

    # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
    # we want the workers on top
    self._layer = 2
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)

    # let's keep track of the state and how long we are in this state already            
    self.state = Worker.IDLE
    self.ticks_in_state = 0

    self.image = self.images[self.state]
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)

    self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
    self.speed = random.randint(1, 3)
    self.set_random_direction()


  def set_random_direction(self):
    # random new direction or standing still
    vec = pygame.math.Vector2(random.randint(-100,100), random.randint(-100,100)) if random.randint(0, 5) > 1 else pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

    # check the new vector and decide if we are running or fooling around
    length = vec.length()
    speed = sum(abs(int(v)) for v in vec.normalize() * self.speed) if length > 0 else 0

    if length == 0 or speed == 0:
        new_state = Worker.IDLE
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
    else:
        new_state = Worker.RUNNING
        self.direction = vec.normalize()

    self.ticks_in_state = 0
    self.state = new_state

    # use the right image for the current state
    self.image = self.images[self.state]


  def update(self, screen):
    self.ticks_in_state += 1
    # the longer we are in a certain state, the more likely is we change direction
    if random.randint(0, self.ticks_in_state) > 70:
        self.set_random_direction()

    # now let's multiply our direction with our speed and move the rect
    vec = [int(v) for v in self.direction * self.speed]
    self.rect.move_ip(*vec)

    if any(s for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, fences, False) if s != self):
        print("RISK_LEVEL: ",fences.risk_level)


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
workers = pygame.sprite.Group()
fences = pygame.sprite.Group()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST")

# create multiple workers
for pos in ((30,30), (50, 400), (200, 100), (700, 200)):
    Worker("w1.png", "w2.png", pos, all_sprites, workers, fences)

# create multiple geo-fences
risks = ["HIGH","MEDIUM","LOW"]
for rect in (pygame.Rect(510,150,75,52), pygame.Rect(450,250,68,40), pygame.Rect(450,370,68,48)):
    risk = risks[random.randint(0,2)]
    GeoFence(rect, risk, all_sprites, fences)
```

**UPDATE:**

For @Prune: [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724335/how-to-change-an-image-of-a-sprite-during-the-animation) that contains the whole code if there is any problem to reproduce this example.

Comment: @Prune: Do you mean that is fails at the line `class GeoFence(pygame.sprite.Sprite):`? How can it fail at this line. EDIT: You deleted all your comments, while have not answered my questions about downvoting.

Comment: Please post [minimal, runnable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error will get raised here:

```
if any(s for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, fences, False) if s != self):
    print("RISK_LEVEL: ", fences.risk_level)
```

`fences` is a sprite group and it doesn't have a `risk_level` attribute, only the `GeoFence` sprites in this group have this attribute. So you need to figure out which sprites have collided with the worker and then access the `risk_level` of these sprites. The simplest solution would be to iterate over the collided sprites with a `for` loop (replace the two lines above with):

```
for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, fences, False):
    print("RISK_LEVEL: ", s.risk_level)
```